# Нужно ли выделить запятыми одиночное деепричастие?

Tags: запятая

Зрители, стоя, бурными аплодисментами приветствовали звезд.

Answer (score 1):

Одиночное деепричастие не выделяется запятыми, если употребляется в наречном значении или может быть заменено наречием. В данном предложении "стоя" - это деепричастие в наречном значении, значит, запятая не нужна